# How to correctly selectively redirect certain LAN devices, to use VPN or clearnet gateway, using iptables?

Tags: iptables, dd-wrt

I am using dd-wrt and was able to get VPN working on it, the problem is I want to have the default to be routing traffic through the VPN but have the option of also routing through the clearnet gateway. Currently I have:

```
WAN_IF=`nvram get wan_iface

iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o $WAN_IF -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -p tcp -o $WAN_IF -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -p udp -o $WAN_IF -j REJECT --reject-with udp-reset
```

problem is, that seems to block everything that tries to go through the regular wan which makes for a nice killswitch of sorts but I need at least one device/computer to have direct access to the internet and not through the VPN?
I was thinking to block everything except one MAC address like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i br0 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:12:34:56:78:9A -j ACCEPT
```

but that obviously didnt work.
I have spent the afternoon trying to wrap my head around iptables and ... its been a long afternoon, pointing out how to correct what I have would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `nvram get wan_iface` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i br0 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:12:34:56:78:9A -j ACCEPT
```

- wrong chain: `iptables -I FORWARD 1`
- MAC check reversed: `-m mac --mac-source`